# onError called in promise

Tags: javascript, html, swift

I wrote a web-based app that I want to display in a webview on my iPhone. My plan is to load this website assets by promises:

I wrote this code to load some of my images I'll need for drawing to my canvas later on:

```
constructor() {
    this.assets = {
      "assets/y/y/background.png" : 0,
      "assets/y/spritesheet.png" : 0,
      "assets/x/spritesheet.png" : 0,
      "assets/x/background.png" : 0,
      "assets/x/background.png" : 0,
      "assets/z/spritesheet.png" : 0,
      "assets/z/background.png" : 0,
      "assets/z/a/spritesheet.png" : 0,
      "assets/p/a/spritesheet.png" : 0,
      "assets/p/a/spritesheet.png" : 0,
    }
    this.init()
}
async init() {
    await this.loadAssets()
    $("#information").html("successfully started")
}

async loadAssets() {
    for (let asset in this.assets) {
      let image = new Image()
      image.src = "https://myWebserver.info/" + asset
      $("#information").html("loading asset<br>" + asset)
      await new Promise(resolve => {
          image.onload = () => {
            resolve(image);
          }
          image.onerror = (e) => {
            $("#information").html("error asset<br>" + image.src)
          }
      });
      this.assets[asset] = image
    }
  }
```

The **js code** above is working quite fine running it on my Mac - but I got big Problems with my WKWebView in Swift. Launching the app will cause around every second time that I get an error for the loading of an image.

My first thought was that it might just be a corrupt picture, but it's not: The picture that makes a mistake is different every time - seemingly by chance.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this problem and still reload the faulty image in case of an error?

I am really helpless.

Comment: Did you look at the network requests?

Comment: Good point... but nope - no idea how to do this with my webview on my iPhone tbh @epascarello

Comment: Why is the `load` event within `Promise` constructor though `image` declaration is not? Is the error an `UnhandledPromiseRejection` error? Have you tried using `try..catch` to handle the error?